# Spring MVC xml data '&' converting to '&amp;amp;'

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

Hi All in My Spring MVC application.
I am storing the form data as XML in the DB.
Using JAXB Class and Marshaller, JAXBContext etc.

Now Problem in on '&'

If text field have **'ABC & XYZ'**
it is storing in DB as **ABC &amp; XYZ**

```
<individualOrOrganisation>I</individualOrOrganisation>
  <detailsoftheArtsEntertainment>
    <titleofEvent>ABC &amp;amp; XYZ</titleofEvent>
  </detailsoftheArtsEntertainment>
```

And Displaying as **ABC & XYZ**

I am using StringTrimmerEditor and initBinder to Trim all user Input text Data.

Please help me how to handle this.